# better way to validate input?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a bit of code that takes 5 grades from user input and checks to see if a grade is 0 to 100 or if the input is a non-numerical value and keeps trying until you give it valid input.

```
def main(x):
    counter = 0
    grade = x
    grades = [0] * 5
    incount = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
    average = 0
    restart = ""

    # try 5 times to validate input and set the 5 grades if valid
    while counter < 4:
        try:
            grade = int(grade)
            if grade > 100 or grade < 0:
                print("Please enter a number from 0 to 100!")
            else:
                grades[counter] = grade
                counter = counter + 1
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid numerical value.")
        grade = input("Enter the " + incount[counter] + " grade. ")
    grades[counter] = grade
```

The problem is on the 5th grade if it does not validate. What could I change to make sure the 5th one validates and can also start using this module

```
def start():
    grade = 0
    print("To get a grade average, please enter five grades one by one from 
    0 to 100.")
    grade = input("Enter the first grade. ")
    main(grade)
```

EDIT:

```
    while counter < 5:
        try:
            grade = int(grade)
            if grade > 100 or grade < 0:
                print("Please enter a number from 0 to 100!")
            else:
                grades[counter] = grade
                counter = counter + 1
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid numerical value.")
        if counter < 5:
            grade = input("Enter the " + incount[counter] + " grade. ")
    grades[counter - 1] = grade
```

I took the advice to loop an extra time but I did not want to add a decision statement to avoid another input on the last loop. It seems to be a cheap fix for the last loop but I can't figure out how to get all 5 values validated without taking another input otherwise.

Comment: Can you reformat this to be valid Python code, so that we can see the concrete problems with your implementation? Pseudocode can not be tested, and the question should not be tagged `python` unless it actually is related to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only iterating 4 times in your while loop since your condition is a strict inferiority.

`counter` takes only the following values : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. But for 4 it doesn't output `TRUE` to the condition

You should change the max value from 4 to 5 **OR** change your operator from `<` to `<=`

Comment: I would also have to stop taking input on the 5th loop and that takes up another decision, maybe that is my only option

Comment: Can you be clearer about that? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: At the end of each loop, another input is taken. On the 5th loop, at the end another input would be taken giving 6 input values and producing an error.

Comment: No, it only asks you five times to input a grade.

Comment: no on the 5th run it asks for input again just look at code

Comment: it asks for input again but it is the 5th request not the 6th

Comment: the last thing the loop does is ask for input, think about it. before the loop starts it already has input, so on the 5th run (not the 6th) a 6th INPUT record would be taken. therefore i put a check before the input is taken to see if it is the last run, do you understand?

Comment: Well no. On the 5th run, you store your grade, then you increment `counter`, then you check if `counter` is less than 5 (which is False because `counter = 5` at this time), so you don't enter the `if` and you don't ask for another input.

Comment: no, at the end of each loop input is taken. you are completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have diverged from your preferred solution direction and decided to go with a self calling function with some checks for call counter and grades length

There is also a custom exception for numbers < 0 or > 100 that is raised and caught to give the desired user flow.

```
# coding: utf-8
class InvalidIntError(Exception):
    ''' our custom exception '''
    pass


def average_grade(grades_marks, grade_title, counter):
    grades = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

    # for the first loop use the original grades list
    if counter > 0:
        # for subsequent calls to this function always start looping grades from passed grade_title
        current_index = grades.index(grade_title)
        new_grades = grades[current_index:]
        print(
            f'The current index {current_index} , the current grades {new_grades}'
        )
        grades = new_grades

    try:
        print(f'Counter {counter}, using grades :> {grades}')

        for grade_title in grades:
            grade = int(input(f'Enter the {grade_title} grade :> '))
            if grade > 100 or grade <= 0:
                raise InvalidIntError(
                    f'Your grade is < 0 or > 100.Enter the {grade_title} grade :> '
                )
            grade = int(grade)
            grades_marks.append(grade)
            print(grades_marks)
            counter += 1
        print('Gotten grade values calculating the average')
        average = sum(grades_marks) / len(grades_marks)
        print(f'grades given as {grades_marks},\n the average is :> {average}')
    except ValueError as e:
        # means we have given a non integer, so rerun function
        print('error ', e)
        average_grade(grades_marks, grade_title, counter)
    except InvalidIntError as e:
        # an int < 0 or > 100
        print('error ', e)
        average_grade(grades_marks, grade_title, counter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grades_marks = []
    average_grade(grades_marks, 'first', 0)
```

Sample run

```
$ python infinite_validation.py
Counter 0, using grades :> ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Enter the first grade :> 20
[20]
Enter the second grade :> f
error  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
The current index 1 , the current grades ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Counter 1, using grades :> ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Enter the second grade :> g
error  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g'
The current index 1 , the current grades ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Counter 1, using grades :> ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Enter the second grade :> f
error  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
The current index 1 , the current grades ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Counter 1, using grades :> ['second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
Enter the second grade :> 20
[20, 20]
Enter the third grade :> 40
[20, 20, 40]
Enter the fourth grade :> 12
[20, 20, 40, 12]
Enter the fifth grade :> 9000000000000221211
error  Your grade is < 0 or > 100.Enter the fifth grade :>
The current index 4 , the current grades ['fifth']
Counter 4, using grades :> ['fifth']
Enter the fifth grade :> 40
[20, 20, 40, 12, 40]
Gotten grade values calculating the average
grades given as [20, 20, 40, 12, 40],
 the average is :> 26.4
```

NB: You can remove some of the excessive print debug statements.

Comment: can you explain why i would want to do this? seems like a way overcomplicated way of doing a rather simple task

Comment: this is just an alternative, it might work or not work for you , it uses one function also it captures specific exceptions as opposed to a general except statement, finally it passes much more control to the caller by introducing those three parameters.